# Bounded and Complete Lattices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

Prove or disprove: Every bounded lattice is complete.
It can be easily proved that every complete lattice is bounded. But is the converse true?

Answer (score 4):

How about taking any bounded incomplete linear order like $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$? Alternatively take any incomplete Boolean algebra (for instance a field which is not a $\sigma$-field).